Why are these simple equations so slow to `Solve`?
$Version
(*14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)*)

This set of equations is generated by other codes and hence is redundant:
eqs={-1+a,-1+b,-((-1+a) b),(1-a) b}==0//Thread

and to my surprise, MMA 14.1 cannot solve it directly
TimeConstrained[Timing[Solve[eqs,{a,b}]],10]
(*$Aborted*)

Solve[eqs//Simplify,{a,b}]//Timing
(*{0.000643`,{{a->1,b->1}}}*)

Solve[eqs,{a,b},MaxRoots->1]//Timing
(*{0.001684`,{{a->1,b->1}}}*)

Since Solve has been updated in version 14.1 (and I don't have older ones), is this a bug due to introducing MaxRoots?
Any other example?
Any ad hoc fixing? (I don't want to use Simplify since it's consuming in bad cases.)

Confirmed with friends this does not happen in 14.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 13, 2023), so I believe this is indeed a bug in 14.1.

If no one objects, I will add the tag bug.

Yes, looks like bug. Solve should have removed the duplicated equation. It should not have caused it to hang.

Bug report submitted

The bug (a typo that leads to an infinite loop, fixed for the next version) affects certain systems with more equations than variables.
More precisely, for every k <= the number of variables, the system needs
to contain an equation that involves only the first k variables,
and for some k there need to be at least two equations in k+1 variables
that vanish identically on a solution for the first k variables.
Here, both -((-1 + a) b) and (1 - a) b vanish for a->1.
In such cases one can avoid the buggy code by calling Solve with
Method->{"UseTriangularRoots"->False}.
In[2]:= Solve[eqs, {a, b}, Method->{"UseTriangularRoots"->False}]               
Out[2]= {{a -> 1, b -> 1}}


eqs = {-1 + a, -1 + b, -((-1 + a) b), (1 - a) b} == 0 // Thread
Timing[Solve[Union[Expand@eqs], {a, b}]]


If you expand the equations you see you have one equation repeated
 {-1 + a == 0, -1 + b == 0, b - a b == 0, b - a b == 0}

Doing Union removes the duplicated one. Now it is very fast. For some reason Solve did not see this.

I agree certainly. plz see my new added comments.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

eqs = {-1 + a, -1 + b, -((-1 + a) b), (1 - a) b} == 0 // Thread

(* {-1 + a == 0, -1 + b == 0, -((-1 + a) b) == 0, (1 - a) b == 0} *)

Since you have more equations than Solve variables, use the option MaxExtraConditions
Solve[eqs, {a, b}, MaxExtraConditions -> All] // Timing

(* {0.000579, {{a -> 1, b -> 1}}} *)

